# Windows forms C# - How populate checkedComboBoxEdit1 DevExpert

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I´m new user in DevExpress and I need learning how load data into comboboxCheckbox  the DevExpress windows form.

```cs
conexao = new MySqlConnection("Server=mysql.kmshow.com.br;Database=kmshow14;Uid=kmshow14;Pwd=421843unimed;");
strSQL = "SELECT Id, VENCIMENTO, NUMERO_DOC FROM financeiro_conta ";
da = new MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, conexao);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

How put "dt" in Component?

Answer (score 0):

So you need to do 3 things to get it to work: assign the dt as the datasource, set the DisplayMember to the name of the column that will be shown in the editor, and set the ValueMember for the name of the column that will be used to store data in the database.

The follwing code assumes that you want the Id column to be the value and the NUMERO_DOC column to be displayed to the user.

```
checkedComboBoxEdit1.Properties.DataSource = dt;
checkedComboBoxEdit1.Properties.DisplayMember = dt.NUMERO_DOCColumn.ColumnName;
checkedComboBoxEdit1.Properties.ValueMember = dt.IdColumn.ColumnName;
```